# Dell Secure Boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, dell, secure-boot

I recently bought a new Dell laptop. When I run updates, I'm routinely warned that I have "secure boot enabled", and that it might break "third party drivers". It then recommends that I disable it, but this requires that I enter a password, which I don't have. If I instead opt to keep it enabled, it does nothing, but then prompts me again when I run an update.

Should I disable secure boot? I haven't rebooted yet since running the update, so I don't know what effect it will have. Is it going to make Ubuntu unbootable if it installs an updated kernel?

If I should keep it enabled, how do I instruct apt-get to not block the install with a warning?

Edit: The "Additional Drivers" gui says I'm not using any proprietary drivers.

Comment: If you need proprietary drivers for video or Internet then you need to have secure boot off. If not it should work whether on or off, but grub cannot be used to boot Windows, only UEFI boot menu. In those  cases the chain of secure boot gets lost, so then Secure boot does not work. If plain vanilla Ubuntu and you want to boot  from UEFI boot menu then Secure boot should work.

Comment: @oldfred, there is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464) that ***can*** prevent launching Windows from GRUB with Secure Boot enabled; but I'm pretty sure that this bug affects only some computers. Many others are unaffected by this problem. As to disabling Secure Boot, see [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) for several examples. Unfortunately, it differs from one computer to another.